# SLF4j multiple bindings exception

Tags: apache, hadoop, flume-ng, flume-twitter

[error screenshot here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g0nOJ.png)

I am trying to stream real time twitter data into HDFS using Apache flume. And when i run the command ./flume-ng agent -c /usr/local/apache-flume-1.4.0-bin/conf/ -f /usr/local/apache-flume-1.4.0-bin/conf/flume.conf -n TwitterAgent it gives me a SLF4j exception. It does not allow the program to run further. Any suggestions to solve this issue would be of immense help

Comment: That is only a warning and is not stopping the flume agent. Add `-Dflume.root.logger=DEBUG,console` to the flume command to see the logs in console.

Comment: can you share the error log